# sub columns in sql table

Tags: sql

I want to create a table named now showing(movies) in that one column will be of ticket price in ticket price i have 3 options silver,gold,platinum, I know that I will have to create different table for ticket price but how to connect both tables? which field will be better for primary and foreign keys?

Comment: Show us your current design attempt.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: currently using SQL database

Comment: SQL is a query language. **Every** relational database is a "SQL database".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE PRICES (
    PriceID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO-INCREMENT,
    PriceOption STRING
);

CREATE TABLE NOWSHOWING (
    MovieID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO-INCREMENT,
    PriceID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PRICES(PriceID),
    [probably some more stuff]
);

INSERT INTO PRICES (PriceOption) VALUES ('Platinum');
INSERT INTO PRICES (PriceOption) VALUES ('Gold');
INSERT INTO PRICES (PriceOption) VALUES ('Silver');
```

Is that what you're looking for ?